# "Grid Fill" error: Loops are not connected by wire/boundary edges

Tags: mesh, vertices

I tried to Grid Fill. The selected vertices are an even number. But Blender throws error "Loops are not connected by wire/boundary edges". What did I do wrong? What do "wire/boundary edges" even mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you post a picture of your selection before running the command?

Comment: Also try to make sure you remove doubles.

Comment: Did indeed remove the doubles.

Comment: you might have to provide us with that section of the model's mesh. normally GridFill will fill even the craziest boundaries. Maybe you would consider making a copy of your blend and deleting all the sections that you don't want to share, but leave a small section around the area in question .. and upload here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try deleting the face you have selected, then select the edge loop and use grid fill.

Comment: @TavernSenses how much effort would it be for you to make a copy of the .blend and remove most of the unrelated geometry , then upload as a .blend to the site linked above? If you really want answers .. maybe you found a bug? it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. After having gained some more experience, I find that hiding the visible geometry often reveals the double and even triple vertices. So that works best for me now